# How to change color to multiple objects in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I need to change the color of a lot of buttons , textboxes and forms but I do not want something like that: (pseudocode)

```
button1.color = blue
button2.color = blue
```

I want something like:

```
AllButtons.color = blue
```

(when I say color I mean background color, focused color and others, and no, it isn't  the same color.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Me.Controls.OfType`

```vb
For Each b In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)
    b.BackColor = Color.Blue
    b.ForeColor = Color.Red
Next
```

You can also make a method which takes a type and changes all the controls of that type

```vb
Public Sub ChangeAllColors(Of T As Control)(backColor As Color, foreColor As Color)
    For Each c In Me.Controls.OfType(Of T)
        c.BackColor = backColor
        c.ForeColor = foreColor
    Next
End Sub
```

```vb
ChangeAllColors(Of Button)(Color.Blue, Color.Red)
```

But this only changes the controls immediately in `Me`. Do you want to change all the controls in Me, its containers, their containers, etc? Then you can combine it with this extension method in a module

```vb
<Extension>
Public Function ChildControls(parent As Control) As IEnumerable(Of Control)
    Return ChildControls(Of Control)(parent)
End Function

<Extension>
Public Function ChildControls(Of TControl As Control)(parent As Control) As IEnumerable(Of TControl)
    Dim result As New List(Of TControl)
    For Each ctrl As Control In parent.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is TControl Then result.Add(CType(ctrl, TControl))
        result.AddRange(ctrl.ChildControls(Of TControl)())
    Next
    Return result
End Function
```

```vb
For Each b In Me.ChildControls(Of Button)
    b.BackColor = Color.Blue
    b.ForeColor = Color.Red
Next
```

```vb
Public Sub ChangeAllColors(Of T As Control)(backColor As Color, foreColor As Color)
    For Each c In Me.ChildControls(Of T)
        c.BackColor = backColor
        c.ForeColor = foreColor
    Next
End Sub
```

```vb
ChangeAllColors(Of Button)(Color.Blue, Color.Red)
```

That first extension method makes this possible

```vb
For Each b In Me.ChildControls()
    b.BackColor = Color.Blue
    b.ForeColor = Color.Red
Next
```

(Have a nice trip!)